# Asynchronous Jsonp Call in angular js

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, angularjs-scope

In my angular application i need to do three jsnop Requests One by one. But i am getting only last request response. Here i am building the urls dynamically.

```
$scope.getCurrentMonthData = function(){
        $scope.location_key = 5124302;
        $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.startday = 1;
        $scope.currentday = $scope.date.getDate()+1;
        $scope.month = $scope.date.getMonth()+1;
        $scope.year = $scope.date.getFullYear();
        $scope.start= $scope.year+'/'+$scope.month+'/'+$scope.startday;

        $scope.end = $scope.year+'/'+$scope.month+'/'+$scope.currentday;

        $scope.url1 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/actuals/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $scope.url2 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/records/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $scope.url3 = $rootScope.ApiWeatherHost+'/climo/v1/normals/'+$scope.location_key+'.json?start='+$scope.start+'&end='+$scope.end+'&apikey='+$rootScope.ApiKey+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $http.jsonp($scope.url1).then(function(msg){
          console.log(msg.data);
        });
       $http.jsonp($scope.url2).then(function(msg){
          console.log(msg.data);
        });
        $http.jsonp($scope.url3).then(function(msg){
          console.log(msg.data);
        });

  };
```

Her i am not getting the first two requests.

Comment: Have you tried $promise.then()? Also, have you considered migrating your $http into a $resource factory?

Comment: Do you use `Fiddler`, or any browser development tools, where you can see requests and responses? Can you confirm you never get reply back? Or if your requests are failing?

Comment: @michaelmoore I am getting 404 error there. The data is not substituting in the first two requests. I am getting the data at 3 request

Comment: `404` means `Not Found`, so I would suggest to check your first 2 urls, and make sure you have correct urls.

Comment: @michaelmoore Ya i checked it. I am getting JSON Responses. But not getting the JSONP Responses.

Comment: @michaelmoore Here is my code..
http://codepen.io/dustin/pen/DJIKi

Comment: @mani I would suggest to change your `jsonp` calls from `$http.jsonp($scope.url1).then(function(msg){ console.log(msg.data); });` to `$http.jsonp($scope.url1).success(function(msg){ console.log(msg.data);});`